# Call Spring service and send params via Constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have this simple Spring Service:

```
@Service
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

    @Autowired
    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

    private Terminals terminal;    

    @Autowired
    public BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(Terminals terminal) {  
        this.terminal = terminal;
    }
}
```

`Terminals` is a object unique for each received request. Also `binCountryCheckFilter` should be unique for every request - it should check the data for some business condition.

I want to call the service from here:

```
@Service
public class FilterProcessing {

    @Autowired
    private BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilter; 

    public Response someMetohd(Terminals terminal,
              Transaction message, HttpServletRequest request) throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {

        switch(.......) {
            case ".......":
                // send here the args via Contructor
                binCountryCheckFilter.validateBinCountryCheckFilter(terminal);                  
                break;
            case ".........":           
                .........
                break;

                break;                                          
            }           
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I'm not aware how to send the object `terminal` via the `BinCountryCheckFilterImpl` constructor.
Is there some solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is meant to create objects. 
You say: "send here the args via Constructor" - but this means that you should **create** a new object of type `BinCountryCheckerFilterImpl` for every request, and this is not how that class is defined.

In your case `BinCountryCheckFilterImpl` is a bean with (default) scope singleton, meaning that only one instance of this class exists in the application context.

So instead of using parameter in constructor, just pass `Terminals` object (that is created per request) into the validation method:

```
@Service
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

  @Autowired
  private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

  public void validateBinCountryCheckFilter(Terminals terminal) {

  }
}
```

If you really have to define the `BinCountryCheckFilterImpl` to be a prototype, you should be aware that prototypes cannot be injected into singletons by simple Autowiring.

There are many techniques for this, you can find the answers [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton). I don't describe them in the answer because I feel its out of scope of the question and you should really go with the solution I've provided above.